# google sitemap index, nothing indexed, all children pending

Tags: xml, indexing, sitemap, google-search-console

I submitted a sitemap index to google sitemaps, https://studypool.com/sitemap.xml, that has over 10 children sitemaps, but a week later google webmaster still hasn't indexed any of the sitemaps.

In the "type" category it says "?" and status is "pending." Google says it takes 5-6 hours, but its been a week. I checked DNS records and the format of the sitemap against google's examples, but nothing seems wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's been resolved. Just took a few months.